# Where is the client side ssh config file(/etc/ssh/ssh_config) for Windows 10 powershell?

Tags: powershell, ssh

I would like to configure the timeout for the ssh client that comes default in Windows 10 powershell?
I know in ubuntu/WSL, it is */etc/ssh/ssh_config* and it does work in WSL on the same PC but the timeout for my powershell is still low. Where do I configure it?

Reference for Ubuntu ssh config file: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/261905/379247

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per user config:

```
$env:USERPROFILE\.ssh\config
```

Global config:

```
$env:ProgramData\ssh\ssh_config
```

Comment: For anyone wondering, the directory can be viewed with: `Get-ChildItem Env:UserProfile`. In this directory, you should see `.ssh` which is the same directory with the SSH keys.